# Getting file as undefined when sent in an object array using FormData.append

Tags: angular, file-upload

I am trying to send array of object to backend.
each array element will contain object with  field price & file,
**Objective is to send array of object to API**

```
let attachmentArray = [
    {
      file: '',
      price: '2000'
    },
    {
      file: '',
      price: '1000'
    }
  ];

 selectAttachment(event, i) {
    const file: File = event.target.files[0];
    if (file) {
      const fileName = file.name;
      // this.attachmentArray[i].fileName = fileName;
      this.attachmentArray[i].file = file;
    }
    console.log(file);
  }

 this.attachmentArray.forEach((el, i) => {
  let formData = new FormData();
  el['file'] = formData.append('file', el.file);
});
```

Getting file **undefined**

[code link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-3hwcmv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

[image: response in console]

Comment: You're posting an array of form data, but shouldn't you be posting a single form with an array of files instead?

Comment: U mean to say, put entire form in formData.append('form', this.attachmentArray) like this, instead of sending file  formData.append('file', el.file) ? @Silvermind

Comment: Not like that. Check out this tutorial: https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-file-upload/